# Gridview performance with HttpResponseCache

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm using a gridview to display hundreds of images (perhaps even a few thousand). The images are located on a server and I'm caching the images using [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html). The problem I'm having is that when I swipe down through the gridview, the recycled views are showing 3 or more images, per child view, before finally settling on the correct image. It seems to be a result of the callback methods returning all the requested images. How can I get a gridview to not have this giant swoosh of activity when scrolling up/down.

getView method of my custom adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;

        if (convertView == null) {

            v = li.inflate(R.layout.folder_button, null);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvFolderButtonTitle);

        tv.setText(mBaseItems[position].Name);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivFolderButtonImage);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(folderWidth_, folderHeight_));
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        String imageUrl = "http://path.to.image";
        api_.GetImageAsync(imageUrl, new GetImageStreamCallback(iv), false);

        return v;           
}
```

callback method that sets the image.

```
public class GetImageStreamCallback implements IApiCallback {

private ImageView currentImageView;

public GetImageStreamCallback(ImageView imageView) {
    currentImageView = imageView;
}

public void Execute(Object data) {

    if (data != null) {
        try {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data;
            currentImageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception", "Error getting image");
        }
    }
}

}
```

custom AsyncTask called from api_.GetImageAsync above

```
public class AsyncRequestImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,Object > {

HttpURLConnection connection_;
InputStream inStream_;
IApiCallback callback_;
boolean ignoreCache_;

public AsyncRequestImage(IApiCallback callback, boolean ignoreCache) {
    this.callback_ = callback;
    this.ignoreCache_ = ignoreCache;
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(String... uri) {

    Bitmap image;

    if (ignoreCache_) {
        image = acquireImage(uri[0], true);
    } else {
        image = acquireImage(uri[0], false);
        if (image == null)
            image = acquireImage(uri[0], true);
    }

    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object image) {
    callback_.Execute(image);
}   

private Bitmap acquireImage(String url, boolean ignoreCache) {
    try {
        URL _url = new URL(url);

        connection_ = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
        connection_.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        if (ignoreCache) {
            connection_.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        } else {
            connection_.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");
        }

        connection_.connect();

        String encoding = connection_.getContentEncoding();

        // Determine if the stream is compressed and uncompress it if needed.
        if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {

            try {
                inStream_ = new GZIPInputStream(connection_.getInputStream());                          
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }

        }  else {

            try {
                inStream_ = connection_.getInputStream();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }

        if (inStream_ != null) {

            try {
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream_);
                return image;

            } catch (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError oom) {                  
                FileLogger.getFileLogger().ReportInfo("UrlConnection: Bitmap creation failed. Out of memory");                  
            }                               
        }           

    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (e != null && e.getMessage() != null) {
            Log.i("AsyncRequestImage doInBackground:",e.getMessage());
        }

    } finally {
        connection_.disconnect();
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue I was having was due to an unoptimized BaseAdapter.GetView

Also when the user initiated a fling gesture, I was still trying to load all the images as the views passed by.

[This article](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)! Provided a detailed description and solution for each of the mistakes I was making. Also in that article is a link to source code that provides a method to stop loading images until the fling gesture has finished.